# LDAP Server with XML as Backend

Tags: java, xml, ldap, backend

I'm a newbie when it comes to LDAP. I need to setup a basic ldap server for User authentication/authorization from a Java Application. From what I gather it's going to be a small deployment so I was asked for something simple, light and if possible a server that uses XML as a backend.

Can you suggest any possible servers that meet this criteria? I haven't been able to find any that even mentions XML as a backend. Does this exist? I only found that OpenLDAP support a backend built on plain text LDIF files.

==== EDIT ====
I miss phrased the above regarding OpenLDAP and its backend support. I meant that the only server that I was able to find to [easily] support plain text files was OpenLDAP (stated openly in the documentations I researched). 
==== END EDIT ====

Any general pointers on ldap, which product to use, etc is appreciated. I was planning to use the UnboundID API to talk to the server; I haven't decided on what server to use yet (probably ApacheDS).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not expert to answer this. But I would like you to have a look at this links and decide.

http://www.aten.com/data/helpfiles/Ldap_Example.pdf

http://support.sas.com/rnd/itech/doc9/admin_ldap/ldap/index.html

http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LDAP-HOWTO/installing.html

http://www.debuntu.org/ldap-server-and-linux-ldap-clients

http://thoughtblender.info/2008/11/04/comparison-of-directory-ldap-servers/

http://kkalev.wordpress.com/2007/03/14/open-source-ldap-servers-battle/

https://wikis.forgerock.org/confluence/display/OPENDJ/Comparing+OpenDJ

Answer (score 0):

> I only found that OpenLDAP support a backend built on plain text LDIF files.

This is seriously untrue. OpenLDAP supports quite a few backends including BDB, LDIF, SQL, another LDAP server, relay, passwd, null, ...

XML isn't among them but XML would be a poor choice anyway.

What's the problem with using a BDB backend for example?

Comment: Yes, I know that OpenLDAP supports several different backends, sorry for being unclear. What I meant was that OpenLDAP was the only one that I could find that stated to support plain text LDIF as a backend. Also ApacheDS basically supports anything as a storage mechanism or can even be backed in memory but you have to implement the partition yourself.

I don't know the reason for wanting to use XML as a backend, that's what I was requested.